# Dynamic user options using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo

I'm trying to give my users the option to load articles in more languages. 
I'm trying to show a list of available languages that the user hasn't selected, and have a selection of already chosen languages on top for the user to remove from their options.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
class Options_model extends CI_Model{

    protected $options = array(
            'en' => 'English',
            'it' => 'Italiano',
            'fr' => 'Français',
            'de' => 'Deutsch',
            'es' => 'Español',
            'no' => 'Norsk',
            'ru' => 'Русский язык',
            'ar' =>'العربية',
            'zu' => '中文',
            );

    public function my_lang($user_id) {
            $sql = 
            "SELECT lang_id 
            FROM languages 
            WHERE user_id = :user_id";

            $stmt = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $result = $stmt-> fetch();
    }

    public function languages($result) {
            return array_diff_key($this->options, $result);
    }
}
```

and in my view file (for testing, I'll put some of this in the controller when I get it running and throw in links to remove languages and delete the tables from my database).

```
$mylang = $this->Options_model->my_lang($user_id);
print_r($mylang);
foreach ($mylang as $value) {
    echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
}

$options = $this->Options_model->languages($mylang);
echo form_dropdown('languages', $options);
```

and my database is structured as follows :

```
| id | user_id | lang_id |
|------------------------|
| 1  | 12      | en      |
|————————————————————————|
```

All I get when I try to return my $myLang variable is "array". I can't get my array_diff_key function to work and a print_r doesn't look at all like I imagined. I just want to get myself back to my graphics design comfort zone and knock this backend headache out. Is there an easier way to do this? or how should I code user options without looking like an idiot?

Comment: Can you post what you get when you print_r?

Comment: Array ( [lang_id] => en [0] => en ). Also my foreach is echoing twice, but that's easy to explain. I'd like it to echo English, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not massively familiar with PDO, but I think you should use fetchAll() instead of fetch as this will grab all languages as opposed to just the next row.  You'll also want to tell it to use the FETCH_COLUMN mode e.g.

```
return $result = $stmt->->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

This will then return an array of all of the languages as you're expecting, which you should then be able to do your array_diff_key on.